# JMS p2p failover pattern in order to guarantee delivery

Tags: jms, jndi, jboss5.x, esb, message-driven-bean

Im a web developer ended up in some j2ee development (newbie). I sincerely need this theory  confirmed.

I been given the privilege to deliver a message from our system (producer) to the SOA Enterprice service bus (consumer) when the user hits the save button. The information can not be missed or not delivered and the delivery order must be kept.

Environment:

- Jboss eap 5.1 as the producer.
- JNDI server is the ESB (maybe standard).
- Jboss ESB as the consumer.

My weapon of choice is JMS, p2p, due to the asynchronous nature.

When the producer is abut to send the message some problems can occur:

- ESB is down causing JNDI exception
- Queue manager is for some reason not awake or wrongly configured. This should cause some JMS exception.
- Network hickup, causing a JMS error.

So Im looking for some failover pattern. Here is my suggestion:

1. Add a internal JMS queue to which the message is initially added.
2. Add a MDB that listen to the internal queue and tries to send it to the target queue (ESB).
3. If failing in any way log fatal and send email to cool support people.

This should generate a reliable pattern where a message remains on the internal que until processed by the MDB.

Please advice.

Best Regards

ds

Comment: I think that asynchronous and keeping delivery order are at odds.  Certainly MDB's don't guarantee keeping order, quite the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

Well a 'temporary' queue is not a totally bad idea, but during the time from moving data from one queue to putting it on another you'll have a potential window of risk. Even though that window is close to nothing, what would happen if you got some failure right there and then? -You'd have to put the message back on the queue (and there you'd get into the problem with getting it in the correct order - nasty stuff!) or hold on to it in some way until you put it the other queue (which in turn can be cumbersome if you'd e g get into some failure-situaton.
A more stable solution would be to put data in a db with a queue-order column. You can then select your data in the correct order, send it to the new queue, and finally flag it as 'done' or something or even (better?) remove the data in the db.

Comment: what's your guarantee that the queue-order column data is correct?  By which I mean that there's no guarantee that the first message received will be the first processed.  When the message is received, it's not FIFO, so the second message might get put into the db as the first message.  At least this is my understanding.